# Fine Uploader Microsoft Edge File Upload Dialog Infinite Loop

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using Fine Uploader on a site, and the uploading portion of it works perfectly fine on Edge. The issue I've discovered is when I first click the upload button, but instead of selecting a file I close the window or hit cancel, the dialog immediately reopens. It will continue doing this until I select a file for upload.

It seems related to my specific Fine Uploader settings, since the demos on the site don't have the same issue.

Not really sure what could be wrong, the problem is occurring before any upload even takes place.

The HTML for the button:

```
<label id="filelabel">
  <div id="file">CLICK HERE TO UPLOAD PHOTO</div>
</label>
```

This is the JavaScript I have to get it going:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
  //template: 'qq-template',
  button: document.getElementById('file'),
  request: {
    endpoint: '/inc/endpoint.php',
    inputName: 'qqfile'
  },
  validation: {
    acceptFiles: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'],
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf', 'png'],
    itemLimit: 1,
    sizeLimit: 15000000
  },
  multiple: false,
  autoUpload: true,
  callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
      console.log('submit detected');
      return true;
    },
    onUpload: function(id, fileName) {
      console.log('upload detected');
      return true;
    },
    onProgress: function (id, name, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
      var percent = Math.ceil(uploadedBytes / totalBytes * 100);
      $('#fileprogressbar').css('width', percent+'%');
      $('#filepercentage').html(percent+'%');
      if (name.search('pdf') !== -1) {
        $('#filefeedback').css('color','#ff9933');
       $('#filefeedback').html('PDFs require extra processing');
      }
    },
    onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
      if (responseJSON.success) {
        $('#filefeedback').css('color','#093');
        $('#filefeedback').html('File uploaded successfully');
        $('#e_filename').val(responseJSON.uploadName);
      } else {
        $('#e_filename').val('');
        $('#filefeedback').html(responseJSON.error);
      }
    },
    onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhr) {
      console.log('error detected: '+errorReason);
      $('#filefeedback').css('color','#f00');
      $('#filefeedback').html(errorReason);
      $('#e_filename').val('');
      $('#fileprogressbar').css('width', '0%');
      $('#filepercentage').html('0%');
    },
    onCancel: function(id, name) {
      console.log('cancel detected');
      return false;
    },
    onAutoRetry: function(id, name, attemptNumber) {
      console.log('auto retry detected');
      return false;
    }
  },
  debug: false
```

});

Comment: Does this only happen on edge? What if you change the label element to something else, like a div?

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Odd behavior, when I have more time I'll have to see if I can figure out why it was doing this. Adding your answer, but if you want to answer it yourself that will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Ray's answer in my comments:

> Does this only happen on edge? What if you change the label element to
>   something else, like a div?

Comment: Please search the fine uploader issue tracker to see if this has already been filed. If not, please file an issue so it can be tracked.

Comment: seems like a bug in edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8282613/